# How do I format a number in T-SQL for SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
select FORMAT(5,'0#')   --05
select FORMAT(11,'0#')   --11
```

The `Format` function can be used in SQL Server 2012 & 2014, but I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. How I can get the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering only 0-9 needs 0 to be appended before.

```
Declare @num int =5

SELECT CASE 
         WHEN Len(@num) = 1 THEN '0' + Cast(@num AS VARCHAR(10)) 
         ELSE Cast(@num AS VARCHAR(10)) 
       END
```

Comment: How can we do it for format `#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)`,`#,##0.00ISK;-#,##0.00ISK` or `SLRs#,##0.00;(SLRs#,##0.00)`?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT right('0' + convert(varchar,5),2) --05

SELECT right('0' + convert(varchar,11),2) --11
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use Right function. check the below methods :

```
/* Method 1 Using RIGHT function*/

SELECT RIGHT('00' + cast(9 as varchar(5)), 2)


/* Method 2 Using RIGHT AND REPLICATE function*/

SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 2) + cast(9 as varchar(5)), 2)
```

Comment: unless you're dealing with null numbers, if only 2 digits are needed then there's no need to pad with two zeros (though I guess it doesn't hurt). But your example is good from the standpoint of supporting larger digit lengths.

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
 SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST(987654321 AS money), 1)
```